# Materliaze css - Fonts mixed content warning

Tags: css, fonts, materialize

**Blocked loading mixed active content “http://materializecss.com/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2”**

I see mixed content warnings for font downloads in firefox when I try to use a website built on materialize css. My concern is not the warning but, where is the font being requested to be downloaded in the code, i.e.

I do not see any files or refrences containing the links to the Materialize website in the files I have included in my HTML. So, just curious on how is it reaching out to that URL to download them.

EDIT: Here's the snippet from materialize.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Thin), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Light), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Regular), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Medium), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Bold), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Lets see your code then?

Comment: The reason you are getting the mixed content warnings is that the request is for `http` but the requesting page is served over `https`

Answer (score 1):

request is sent from CSS. Search for '@font-face' in your CSS.

Comment: Could you pleas share that whole page?